# How to extract the value from string in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Below are the two line  which i have to parse in the file and **`from first line`** I need to extract `"180000"` and from **second line I** need to extract `"49 , 59, 54 "`.

```
Line 1:
 <Mon Aug  5 15:26:16:040.50 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <Iteration :  1 Duration : 180000 seconds>

Line2:
 <Mon Aug  5 15:26:16:044.93 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Remaining Time : 49 hours 59 min 54 sec >
```

I have written the code but I looks very hard coded one . So if is there any way which i can use please let me know.

My code is :

```
 if($line =~ m/Iteration\s+:\s+1\s+Duration/)
     {
       print"$line\n";
       my @words = split(/ /,$line);
       my $lengh = $#words;
       $Start_Duration = $words[14];
     }

if($line =~ m/Remaining\s+Time\s+:\s+\d+/)
    {
       my @words = split(/ /,$line);
        my $lengh = $#words;
        $Hours= $words[13]*3600;
        $Minuts= $words[15]*60;
        $Seconds= $words[17];
        $Remaining_Time =$Hours+$Minuts+$Seconds;

    }
```

Log:

```
====================================================================================================
<Mon Aug  5 15:26:16:040.50 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <Iteration :  1 Duration : 180000 seconds>


====================================================================================================
<Mon Aug  5 15:26:16:042.11 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Total Weight  : 34>
<Mon Aug  5 15:26:16:042.88 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Total Objects  : 34>

<Mon Aug  5 15:26:16:043.87 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Random Number generated : 3>
<Mon Aug  5 15:26:16:044.40 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Next Test : VideoStreamingSMS_APstress>
<Mon Aug  5 15:26:16:044.93 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Remaining Time : 49 hours 59 min 54 sec >
<Mon Aug  5 15:26:16:045.64 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Test Suite       : concurrency_tests>
<Mon Aug  5 15:26:16:046.26 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Running the test : VideoStreamingSMS_APstress>
<Mon Aug  5 15:26:16:046.81 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Timeout for the test : 1500>
<Mon Aug  5 15:26:16:050.04 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Parameters       : 1>
<Mon Aug  5 15:30:39:760.21 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Random Number generated : 13>
<Mon Aug  5 15:30:39:760.69 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Next Test : CamcorderNoUsb_APstress>
<Mon Aug  5 15:30:39:761.01 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Remaining Time : 49 hours 55 min 31 sec >
<Mon Aug  5 15:30:39:761.28 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Test Suite       : nousb_tests>
<Mon Aug  5 15:30:39:761.54 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Running the test : CamcorderNoUsb_APstress>
<Mon Aug  5 15:30:39:761.77 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Timeout for the test : 1500>
<Mon Aug  5 15:30:39:762.01 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Parameters       : 1>
<Mon Aug  5 15:30:40:017.74 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Test Case : CamcorderNoUsb_APstress>
<Mon Aug  5 15:30:40:018.47 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - uses spiderboard: 0>
<Mon Aug  5 15:32:34:136.59 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Random Number generated : 13>
<Mon Aug  5 15:32:34:137.16 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Next Test : WallpaperToggle_APstress>
<Mon Aug  5 15:32:34:137.60 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Remaining Time : 49 hours 53 min 36 sec >
<Mon Aug  5 15:32:34:137.92 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Test Suite       : feature_tests>
<Mon Aug  5 15:32:34:138.15 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Running the test : WallpaperToggle_APstress>
<Mon Aug  5 15:32:34:138.38 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Timeout for the test : 1500>
<Mon Aug  5 15:32:34:138.61 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Parameters       : 3>
<Mon Aug  5 15:32:34:392.25 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Test Case : WallpaperToggle_APstress>
<Mon Aug  5 15:32:34:392.97 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - uses spiderboard: 0>

<Mon Aug  5 15:32:36:395.53 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <Installation - Waking the Device up and Unlocking it>
<Mon Aug  5 15:32:36:396.17 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <KeyMap_APstress - ADB keyevent : 6>
<Mon Aug  5 15:33:36:407.53 IST 2013> | <DBLOG> <APStress_Command - Timeout on command: adb shell input keyevent 6>
```

Comment: It would be so much better if you posted a larger snippet from the log file, without your comments in the log file. That will give an exact idea of the input format.

Comment: see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups

Comment: There is no `Duration` line in the longer sample that you show.

Comment: @ Borodin .. i think u missed it .. first line it self is Duration line one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program should help you. It is impossible to tell how much verification of the line is necessary without seeing the complete file, so it is possible that you need more elaborate regular expressions to check that the right lines are being processed.

It is dubious practice to use capital letters in variable names, as they are generally reserved for constants in Perl code, like package names.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $start_duration;
my ($hours, $minutes, $seconds);
while (<DATA>) {
  if (/Duration\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*seconds/) {
    $start_duration = $1;
  }
  elsif (/Remaining Time\s*:\s*([^>]+)/) {
    ($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = $1 =~ /\d+/g;
  }
}

say $start_duration;
say join ', ', $hours, $minutes, $seconds;


__DATA__
<Mon Aug  5 15:26:16:040.50 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <Iteration :  1 Duration : 180000 seconds>
<Mon Aug  5 15:26:16:044.93 IST 2013> | <MNLOG> <TestRunnerUnit - Remaining Time : 49 hours 59 min 54 sec >
```

**output**

```
180000
49, 59, 54
```